DAX Dynamic Measure Assist with Recursion
I am creating a Measure that works as expected, however I have to hard-code the variables depending on how many 'Periods' my sample table contains so this is not feasible for say 1,000 periods
Any ideas how I can enhance this measure using for example GENERATE SERIES and VALUES virtual table? If I have a variable or measure that contains the MAX number of Periods?
MN = 

VAR period = SELECTEDVALUE(Samples[Period], 0)

VAR pFactor2 = CALCULATE(
    ([ProdUnitsCumulative] - SUM(Samples[ProdUnits])) * (1+0)/ ([ProdUnitsCumulative] )
    , FILTER(ALL(Samples), Samples[Period] == 2))

VAR pFactor3 = CALCULATE(
    ([ProdUnitsCumulative] - SUM(Samples[ProdUnits])) * (1+pFactor2)/ ([ProdUnitsCumulative] )
    , FILTER(ALL(Samples), Samples[Period] == 3))

VAR pFactor4 = CALCULATE(
    ([ProdUnitsCumulative] - SUM(Samples[ProdUnits])) * (1+pFactor3)/ ([ProdUnitsCumulative] )
    , FILTER(ALL(Samples), Samples[Period] == 4))

VAR pFactor5 = CALCULATE(
    ([ProdUnitsCumulative] - SUM(Samples[ProdUnits])) * (1+pFactor4)/ ([ProdUnitsCumulative] )
    , FILTER(ALL(Samples), Samples[Period] == 5))

VAR pFactor6 = CALCULATE(
    ([ProdUnitsCumulative] - SUM(Samples[ProdUnits])) * (1+pFactor5)/ ([ProdUnitsCumulative] )
    , FILTER(ALL(Samples), Samples[Period] == 6))    

RETURN 
SWITCH(true(),
    period == 1, 0,
    period == 2, pFactor2,
    period == 3, pFactor3,
    period == 4, pFactor4,
    period == 5, pFactor5,
    period == 6, pFactor6,
    0
)

Expected Slope is what I am trying to achieve with this MN measure


It is not a straight forward linear regression or trend line, since it looks like this over many periods which is correct according to business.


What is this calculation doing or is there an analysis name for it? What is MN abbreviation? Trying to determine if there is an alternative calculation since this could be a significant performance hit. If you could also provide sample data and expected results for say 6 rows then it would be a great help.

Hi
This produces a factor similar to a linear trend but not quite.
MN means nothing just a placeholder.
I will edit the primary thread soon with a screenshot of what this produces which is used downstream by business .... and the results must be the same ...

I included more graphics and explanation in the main post.
